# Give a javascript alert after submit JSP without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am entering data into a jsp page and validating it from the database. I need to give an alert on the JSP page if the validation is false without refreshing the page as the user is forced to re-enter all the details when the page is refreshed:
My validation Method:

```
public boolean accountCifMismatch(String account, String custid) {
        Connection conn;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            conn = db.getDbConnection();
            String sql = pr.getDBProperty().getProperty("com.crb.accountCifMismtach");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, account);
            ps.setString(2, custid);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                count = rs.getInt(1);
            }
            DBConnection.closeConn(conn);
            System.out.println(MemoryListener.getMemoryDetails());
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return count == 0;
    }
```

My servlet call:

```
Fraud fmd = new Fraud();
 if (!fmd.accountCifMismatch(account_no, cust_id)) {
//Continue Processing
} else {
          session.setAttribute("accountcifmismtach", true);
          session.setAttribute("content_page", "fraud.jsp");
             }
```

and on `fraud.jsp` I call a javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (${accountcifmismtach == 'true'}) {
        alert("Account Number CIF Mismtach");
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT** I am submitting the form:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=doFindFraud">
</form>
```

The alert shows and then the page is refreshed, so the user has to input all the details once more. How can I show the alert without refreshing the page?

Comment: are you submitting the form or AJAX call?

Comment: Is there any method using for submission?

Comment: you need to send ajax call to validate email, if correct then submit form

Comment: I am just submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate the Form without refreshing the Page , You need to use AJAX .

There are many ways to make ajax calls but with Java Programming Language I prefer [DWR(Direct Web Remoting)Easy AJAX for java](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

**DWR Way** :

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/index.html

Other Famous ways listed below :

**JQUERY Way**

```
 // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                        encode          : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data); 

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
            });
```

**JavaScript (No Jquery Required)**

```
function AJAXPost(formId) {
    var elem   = document.getElementById(formId).elements;
    var url    = document.getElementById(formId).action;        
    var params = "";
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (elem[i].tagName == "SELECT") {
            value = elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value;
        } else {
            value = elem[i].value;                
        }
        params += elem[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "&";
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { 
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(params);

    return xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: OK thanks. I am very new to AJAX how would I apply it in My case?

Answer (score 0):

Write return false after alert and focus the required input form element in javascript.

Ex: docuemnt.getElementById('requiredInputElement').fous;